# How to display categories in segments in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to be able to display categories in range in different divs e.g.

(div 1) Cat 1, Cat 2, Cat 3, Cat 4 (/div) 
 (div 2) Cat 5, Cat 6, Cat 7, Cat 8 (/div)

Below is what i have. As you can see, it basically pulls all categories and its subcategories

(div 1) Cat 1, Cat 2, Cat 3, Cat 4, Cat 5, Cat 6, Cat 7, Cat 8 (/div)

```
      @foreach ($categories as $key => $cols)
    @foreach ($cols as $iCat)
            <div class="maincategories">
             <?php $attr = ['countryCode' => config('country.icode'), 'catSlug' => $iCat->slug]; ?>
                <?php $attr = ['countryCode' => config('country.icode'), 'catSlug' => $iCat->slug]; ?>
                <div class="maincategories-list clr">
                    <div class="li fleft">
                        <div class="item">
                            <a href="{{ lurl(trans('routes.v-search-cat', $attr), $attr) }}" data-id="{{ $iCat->id }}" class="link parent   ">
                                <span>{{ $iCat->name }}</span>
                                <span class="cat-icon cat-icon-circle cat-icon-{{ $iCat->id }}"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="subcategories-list clr" style="display:none" data-subcategory="{{ $iCat->id }}" id="bottom{{ $iCat->id }}">
                    <div class="subcategories-title">
                        <span class="courierbadge">
                            <span class="ctt-delivery-icon"></span>
                        </span>
                        <a href="{{ lurl(trans('routes.v-search-cat', $attr), $attr) }}" data-id="{{ $iCat->id }}" class="link inlblk"><strong>See all ads</strong></a> in {{ $iCat->name }} </div>
                    <ul>
                        @if (isset($subCategories) and $subCategories->has($iCat->tid))
                        @foreach ($subCategories->get($iCat->tid) as $iSubCat)
                        <li class="fleft">
                            <?php $attr = ['countryCode' => config('country.icode'), 'catSlug' => $iCat->slug, 'subCatSlug' => $iSubCat->slug]; ?>
                            <a data-id="293" data-category-id="{{ $iCat->name }}" href="{{ lurl(trans('routes.v-search-subCat', $attr), $attr) }}" class="link-relatedcategory cat-{{ $iCat->name }} inlblk tdnone icon-link">
                                <span class="link block category-name">
                                            <span>{{ $iSubCat->name }}</span>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                         @endforeach
                    @endif                            
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="category-id-hidden" name="category_id" value="" />
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
```

Comment: By the way, avoid using `<?php ?>` tags, and prefer using `@php` and `@endphp` Blade tags.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides a special `$loop` variable ([Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable)) that you can use at your advantage:

```html
<div> <!-- The div that will contain 4 elements -->
    @foreach (/* your loop */)
        <div>A category</div>

        @if ($loop->index % 4 == 3 && !$loop->last)
            </div>
            <div>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```

`$loop->index` represents the current loop iteration. It starts at 0. `% 4` means "modulo 4", which is the remainder of the division of the current iteration by 4. It means that `$loop->index % 4` will be 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.

By checking if this is equal to 3, it's closing the div and opening another one. I added an additional check, `!$loop->last`, in order to not close+open the div again if there is exactly 4 (or 8, 12, ...) elements, because the last element % 4 would be 3.

Comment: Thanks. Can I display the remaining categories in another div too using similar method?

Comment: @JesseYusufu With this code, the remaining categories (1, 2, or 3) will be in their own div, at the end!